# Filling NaN values from a list with different shape

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = ['A','B','C','D','E'],
             columns = ['date_1','date_2','value_2','value_3','value_4'], 
             data = [['2021-06-28', '2022-05-03', 30, 40, 60],
                     ['2022-01-10', '2022-05-15', 50, 90, 70],
                     [np.nan, '2022-05-15', 40, 60, 80],
                     [np.nan,  '2022-04-28', 40, 60, 90],
                     [np.nan, '2022-06-28', 50, 60, 54]])
```

```
    date_1              date_2          value_2     value_3     value_4
A   2021-06-28          2022-05-03      30          40          60
B   2022-01-03          2022-05-15      50          90          70
C   NaN                 2022-05-15      40          60          80
D   NaN                 2022-04-28      40          60          90
...
E   NaN                 2022-06-28      50          60          54
```

I am trying to fill `NaN` values in column `date_1`. The values I need to fill the `date_1` column are changing every week, the `min` value of `date_1` value need to be`2021-06-28` and the `max` value is `2022-06-20`. Each week the `max` value in `date_1` column will be the last Monday. I need column `date_1` to each date up to `2022-06-20` at least once so that each date starting from `2021-06-28` to `2022-06-20` will be in `date_1` at least once. The order of these values does not matter.

I tried:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()
last_monday = pd.to_datetime((today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())  - timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

# date_mappings is a dictionary with this kind of structure:
# {1 : '2021-06-28', 2 : '2021-07-05', ... 52 : '2022-06-20'}

dates_needed = [x for x in pd.to_datetime(list(date_mappings.values())) if x >= last_monday]
```

So now `dates_needed` has the remaining of the dates that needs to be added at least once in `date_1` column.

The problem I am facing is that the shapes do not match when I try to fill the values, because there can be multiple rows with the same `date_2`.

If I try to use:

```
df.loc[df['date_1'].isna(), 'date_1'] = dates_needed
```

I get:

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Because this only works if I match the shape:

```
df.loc[df['date_1'].isna(), 'date_1'] = [pd.to_datetime('2022-01-10 00:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2022-01-17 00:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2022-01-24 00:00:00')]
```

```
    date_1         date_2           value_2     value_3     value_4
A   2021-06-28     2022-05-03       30          40          60
B   2022-01-10     2022-05-15       50          90          70
C   2022-01-10     2022-05-15       40          60          80
D   2022-01-17     2022-04-28       40          60          90
E   2022-01-24     2022-06-28       50          60          54
```

So my goal is to fill `NaN` values in `date_1` from a created list `dates_needed` where the each date from `dates_needed` is used at least once in `date_1` column and the order does not matter.

Comment: Can you provide the reason of downvotes?

Comment: would you shortage your question and create sample data and provide more clear example?

Comment: I have provided a sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution for mapping by integers from `date_mappings` by helper `Index` by number of missing values by `sum`. Solution working if difference between length of dict vs number of missing values:

```
m = df['date_1'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'date_1'] = (pd.Index(range(m.sum())) + 1).map(date_mappings)
```